# Do we need a CAPTCHA here?

Tags: feature-request

On the front page as of right now, of the 15 questions, 7 are either off-topic or are duplicates.

This makes me wonder if the average person who asks a question on health.se ever reads the guidelines on how to ask a question, and whether we should make it mandatory that they be able to classify a few questions as being on and off topic.  This would then remove nearly 50% of the questions which waste everyones time.

Comment: Not sure how a captcha would make them be able to evaluate on/off topic? And that ability eludes even many high rep users on a lot of sites, not sure how it would go with a brand new user.

Comment: Just provide samples of on and off topic questions, and see if they can classify

Comment: Yessssss I've been advocating for something like this, some sort of hard stop making it mandatory to read and process the guidelines.  They'll get shut down anyways, it's better to slow them down before they post and clog up the question list with duplicates and off topics.

Comment: I'm often asked now to find the odd animal out in Captchas

Comment: We had quite a few suggestions on how to improve this site. But I feel like the will to do change here is just not present (mostly with the SE personel). It’s understandable - we‘re one of many small failing beta sites and hence I‘ve given it up to ask for changes. But feel free to contact a few employees so that they can think about whether to implement such a captcha or not. We could probably talk about a new site name and the other suggestions for improvements as well. // I‘ve tried that and never got a response, and I not have the energy to organise that again.

Comment: Oh well we need to start our own site

Comment: What does typing the name of a street sign in, have to do with evaluating the rules of the site?

Comment: @WakeDemons3 " whether we should make it mandatory that they be able to classify a few questions as being on and off topic. "